# name 'get_default_graph' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

I'm not being able to use `model = Sequential()` in my code. I'm running the code in jupyter notebook in an environment called `ml-learn`. I'm getting an error called `name 'get_default_graph' is not defined`.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 md = bidirectional_lstm_models(seq_length, vocab_size)
      2 md.summary()

 in bidirectional_lstm_models(seq_len, vocab_size)
      1 def bidirectional_lstm_models(seq_len, vocab_size):
      2     model = Sequential()
----> 3     model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256, activation="relu"), input_shape=(seq_len, vocab_size)))
      4     model.add(Dropout(0.6))
      5     model.add(Dense(vocab_size))

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml-learn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml-learn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py in __init__(self, units, activation, recurrent_activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, recurrent_initializer, bias_initializer, unit_forget_bias, kernel_regularizer, recurrent_regularizer, bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, recurrent_constraint, bias_constraint, dropout, recurrent_dropout, implementation, return_sequences, return_state, go_backwards, stateful, unroll, **kwargs)
   2176                         dropout=dropout,
   2177                         recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout,
-> 2178                         implementation=implementation)
   2179         super(LSTM, self).__init__(cell,
   2180                                    return_sequences=return_sequences,

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml-learn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py in __init__(self, units, activation, recurrent_activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, recurrent_initializer, bias_initializer, unit_forget_bias, kernel_regularizer, recurrent_regularizer, bias_regularizer, kernel_constraint, recurrent_constraint, bias_constraint, dropout, recurrent_dropout, implementation, **kwargs)
   1833                  implementation=1,
   1834                  **kwargs):
-> 1835         super(LSTMCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   1836         self.units = units
   1837         self.activation = activations.get(activation)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml-learn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
    130         if not name:
    131             prefix = self.__class__.__name__
--> 132             name = _to_snake_case(prefix) + '_' + str(K.get_uid(prefix))
    133         self.name = name
    134 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml-learn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in get_uid(prefix)
     72     """
     73     global _GRAPH_UID_DICTS
---> 74     graph = get_default_graph()
     75     if graph not in _GRAPH_UID_DICTS:
     76         _GRAPH_UID_DICTS[graph] = defaultdict(int)

NameError: name 'get_default_graph' is not defined
```

Things I tried: 
In file `tensorflow_backend.py` I tried to modify to this: `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph`. I also tried to modify the file I was working on: `tensorflow.keras.models` import `Sequential`. I tried combinations of both. None of these worked.

If someone knows anything about this, please help me!

Comment: Which versions of TensorFlow and Keras are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.13.1. I thought I should be using a version lower than 2.0 for this to work.

Comment: Then add the full traceback.

Comment: Newbie here, not quite sure how to do that :(

Comment: Its the full error message that you get, including any traceback (It starts with "Traceback (most recent call last):")

Comment: lol I'm so silly! I added it

Comment: OK, so which Keras version is this?

Comment: Have you installed Keras separately, or are you using `tf.keras`?

Comment: I have installed Keras separately, but I tried both ways: `tf.keras` and `keras.models...`

Comment: I think the `import` is working. It's just that when I do `models = Sequential()` it shows the log above.

Comment: I think you modified keras' source code, as the code does not match the one in github

Comment: I modified it directly hoping the error would go away. I tried with the original source code as well. Error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were many issues with this question (at least for me). What I did to solve the issue was the following:

1. Install Anaconda from command line: go [here](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) and once download is complete, run `bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2019.10-MacOSX-x86_64.sh` from terminal. Be sure to change the `2019.10` depending on the version you download.
2. Make sure `conda` is installed by typing in `conda list` or anything `conda. -version`.
3. If `conda` doesn't show up for you, then try restarting your terminal. If that doesn't work try `eval “$(/home/msarahan/mc3_dummy/bin/conda shell.bash hook)”`. Replace the directory with yours and then run `conda init`. If that doesn't work, run this: `export PATH="/Users/myname/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"`.
4. Once you do `conda init` it will ask which shell. I'm using `fish` so I chose `fish`.
5. Then run `conda create -n envName`. Replace the `envName` with any enviornment name you like.
6. Activate the enviornment you created: `conda activate envName`.
7. Then open your favorite editor and choose the enviorment you just created.
8. If `jupyter` is not available for your editor (my case: Visual Studio Code), run `conda install -c anaconda jupyter`.
9. Install necessary packages in iTerm (my case) while the enviornment is activated by running: `conda install keras` and `conda install tensorflow` (my case).
10. Verify your installation by running: `pip show keras` and `pip show tensorflow` in your jupyter notebook (my case Visual Studio Code).

To sweeten my problem, I was facing with kernal unexpectedly dying down on me. Therefore, I shut my mac down and turned it on after a bit. Try that as well if you're still unable to fix an error like this (I bet we all leave our macs on sleep lol).